# Selecting from joined tables when relative rows might not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

TSQL gurus, I'm faced with two tables that look something like this:

Table - Names

```
ID(pk)  Name
1       Peter
2       Paul
3       Mary
4       John
5       Fred
```

Table - Cars

```
NameID(pk)  FieldNum    CarText
1           1           Ford
1           2           abcd123
1           3           Mustang
1           4           1967
1           6           Yellow
2           2           qwer456
2           4           1980
3           1           Chevrolet
3           3           Camaro
4           1           Chrysler
4           2           zxcv789
5           4           1970
```

Since all of the names in the first (names) table are required but only FieldNum = 2 (if it exists) is of interest in the second table, the desired output would look something like this:

```
Name        CarText
---------------------
Peter       abcd123
Paul        qwer456
Mary        
John        zxcv789
Fred
```

Or for that matter, an output with some form of null placeholder along these lines would also be usable:

```
Name        CarText
---------------------
Peter       abcd123
Paul        qwer456
Mary        foo
John        zxcv789
Fred        foo
```

Various docs suggest that changing the table joins to a LEFT (or LEFT OUTER) join is the solution. No problem.

```
SELECT Name, CarText
 FROM Names
 LEFT JOIN Cars on Names.ID = Cars.NameID
WHERE Cars.FieldNum = 2
```

But this approach is delivering:

```
Name        CarText
---------------------
Peter       abcd123
Paul        qwer456
John        zxcv789
```

So after amateurishly experimenting with RANK(), ROWNUM, CASE and WHERE EXISTS/NOT EXISTS statements, it feels like the answer is embarassingly close but after a couple of days I just can't nail it.

How can I achieve the desired output, with one table being mandatory but a joined table only contributing a relevant field if/when one exists (or if necessary, in lieu of a related field, some sort of nullish value)?

Comment: The filtering condition needs to be in the JOIN rather than in the WHERE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause is turning the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.  To keep the unmatched rows, move the condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT n.Name, c.CarText
FROM Names n LEFT JOIN
     Cars c
     ON n.ID = c.NameID AND c.FieldNum = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Now I'm glad I asked - this approach was not on my radar at all.

Comment: @KeyserSoze An alternative is to allow for NULLs in the `where` clause, e.g. `... where Cars.FieldNum = 2 or Cars.FieldNum is NULL;` or `... where Coalesce( Cars.FieldNum, 2 ) = 2;`.